# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1

Tags: java, android

I'm making Timetable app. And this error is occurred

I created two activities. One is Main_activity and the other is Popup_Activity. I want to send data from Popup_Activity to Main_Activity.

I have created spinner to select class time

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView,lecture,room,time;
    Button decide;
    EditText enterroom, enterlectrue;
    Spinner spinner;
    int item;
    ClassTime CT = new ClassTime();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup_activity);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setlecture);
        lecture = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lecture) ;
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        room = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.room);

        enterroom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterroom);
        enterlectrue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterlecture);

        decide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decide);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timemenu);

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>
                (this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CT.getTimeList());
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

and I have created ClassTime class.

```
 public class ClassTime {

        private final static Timetable[] TIMES = {
                new Timetable("Mon1",R.id.mon1),
                new Timetable( "Mon2",R.id.mon2), ...


        };

        private final static Map<String,Integer> TIME_MAP = new HashMap<>();

        private final static String[] TIME_LIST;

        static {
            for (Timetable r: TIMES) {
                TIME_MAP.put(r.getTimemenu(),r.gettime());
            }

            TIME_LIST = new String[TIME_MAP.size()];

            TIME_MAP.keySet().toArray(TIME_LIST);
            Arrays.sort(TIME_LIST);
        }

        public String[] getTimeList() { return TIME_LIST; }
        public int getid(String id) { return TIME_MAP.get(id); }
    }
```

I think something is wrong with adapter. Because without that line application is doing well. But if I putted adapter, Application is turned off as soon as I push the button to call the pop_activity.

This is the part of main_activity

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            select_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first);

            return_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.popup);
            setLayout();

        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,intent);
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                int id = intent.getIntExtra("classtime",1);
                if(requestCode ==1) {
                    if (intent == null) {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lecture = intent.getStringExtra("lecture");
                        classroom = intent.getStringExtra("classroom");
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
                        if (idArray[i] == id)
                            select_time = (TextView) findViewById(idArray[i]);
                    }

                    select_time.setText(lecture);
                }
            }

        }
```

I want to get id of textview from spinner. And set the text with `lecture` and `classroom`

What should I change to run app?

**Edit

This is the error :

```
Binary XML file line #19: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f020072 a=-1}
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f020072 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:761)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7012)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:380)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:592)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:313)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:505)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:470)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1331)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

**Popup_activity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/setlecture"
                    android:layout_width="76dp"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:background="#ff7a00"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Set Lecutre"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/timemenu"
                    android:layout_width="249dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="Lecture"
                    android:id="@+id/lecture"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/enterlecture"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="Room"
                    android:id="@+id/room"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/enterroom"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="mOnClose"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="Return"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:id="@+id/decide"
                    android:textColor="#ff7a00"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace, and the relevant layout XML.

Comment: I added stack trace and popup_activity.XML

Comment: The stack trace is that big section of red lines in your logcat that starts with the `InflateException` and message in your title.

Comment: Sorry I edited it

Comment: The problem appears to be in `support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. Is that a layout that you've created?

Comment: No I didn't I thought that is provided by Android studio

Comment: OK, then that's a layout in the support library. If you're using the support library for your app, `PopupActivity` should extend `AppCompatActivity`, rather than `Activity`, and its theme needs to be a `Theme.AppCompat`, or child thereof. Otherwise, use one of the framework layouts, like `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` or `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

Comment: If I change android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" I can't use pop-up design right? What should I find to solve this problem? The code is doing well now really appreciate

Comment: There's a `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` you can use.

Comment: Oh my god Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your App theme is not correct. Change the app theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and in `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

and in manifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

This worked for me.
Have a great Day!